# Firestore rules | Allow to get docs only if doc ids is provided

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Im getting my documents based on a list of ids.

```
db.collection("fruits").where(db.FieldPath.documentId(), "in", fruitIds).get()
```

How should I write my security rules to allow the above call and to deny the below call

```
db.collection("fruits").get()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible exactly as you require.  What you can do is set your rules like this:

```
match /fruits/{id} {
  allow get: true;
  allow list: false;
}
```

This allows clients to get a document if they know the ID, but make it impossible to query documents in bulk.

You will have to then code your client app request each document individually with a DocumentReference `get()` (instead of a Query with a where clause).  The performance hit for this is negligible (no, there is not any noticeable performance gain for using an "in" query the way that you show here - and you are limited to 10 documents per batch anyway).

Comment: This is a good solution, but couldn't they also do a `allow read: if request.data.id != null` ?

Comment: @sleepystar96 No, that would not work.  There is no `request.data`.  See the definition of the [Request object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request).  Also, there is no way in general to do what you're proposing.

Comment: Ah you're right, thanks @Doug

Answer (score 1):

As [@Doug](https://stackoverflow.com/users/807126) covered in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71551060), this is not currently supported in the way you expect.

However, by looking at the [reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request), you can at least limit `list` (query) operations by placing conditions on the `orderBy` and `limit` used by any queries to make it more difficult rather than outright blocking it.

*Consider this answer educational, just fetch the items one-by-one instead and disable list/query access in your security rules. It is included here for those who simply want to obfuscate rather than outright block such queries.*

This would mean changing your query to:

```
db.collection("fruits")
  .where(db.FieldPath.documentId(), "in", fruitIds)
  .orderBy(db.FieldPath.documentId()) // probably implicitly added by the where() above, but put here for good measure
  .limit(10) // this limit applies to `in` operations anyway, but for this to work needs to be added
  .get()
```

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // Matches any document in the cities collection as well as any document
    // in a subcollection.
    match /fruits/{fruit} {
      allow read: if <condition>
      // Limit documents per request to 10 and only if they provide an orderBy clause
      allow list: if <condition>
                  && request.query.limit <= 10
                  && request.query.orderBy = "__name asc" // __name is FieldPath.documentId()
      allow write: if <condition>;
    }
  }
}
```

Using those restrictions, this should no longer work:

```
db.collection("fruits").get()
```

But you could still scrape everything in smaller chunks using:

```
const fruits = [];
const baseQuery = db.collection("fruits")
    .orderBy(db.FieldPath.documentId())
    .limit(10);

while (true) {
  const snapshot = await (fruits.length > 0
    ? baseQuery.startAt(fruits[fruits.length-1]).get()
    : baseQuery.get())

  Array.prototype.push.apply(fruits, snapshot.docs);
  
  if (snapshot.empty) {
    break;
  }
}

// here, fruits now contains all snapshots in the collection
```